# Angular refresh Token

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, refresh-token

I'm trying to implement RefreshToken functionality for my Ionic App. **But apparently the function never executes .flatmap or .mergeMap.** And I'm getting my old 'token' and 'refreshToken' from local storage.  The API consumes following format.

```
  {
  "token": "string",
  "refreshToken": "string"
}
```

Here is my code.

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).catch((errorResponse: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        debugger;
        console.log("Errr Response RefreshTokenInterceptor------", errorResponse);
        debugger;
        const error = (typeof errorResponse.error !== 'object') ? JSON.parse(errorResponse.error) : errorResponse;
        let reqRefData = {
            "token": this.token,
            "refreshToken": this.refresToken
        }

        if (errorResponse.status === 401 && error.error.error === 'Token-Expired') {
            const http = this.injector.get(HttpClient);
            debugger
            let url = Base_Url + 'user/refresh-token';
            console.log(Base_Url + 'user/refresh-token');
            debugger;
            return this.http.post<any>(url, reqRefData)
                // .flatMap(data => {
                .mergeMap(data => {
                    debugger;
                    console.log("!!!!!Flatmap Data ", data);
                    localStorage.setItem('my_token', data.token);
                    debugger;
                    const cloneRequest = request.clone({ setHeaders: { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${data.token}` } });
                    debugger;

                    return next.handle(cloneRequest);
                });
        }

        return Observable.throw(errorResponse);
    });

}}
```

I've also tried using .flatMap and .MergeMap. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Adding `.pipe(mergeMap(.....` does not help?

Comment: See your reqRefData in that your spelling don't match,->"refreshToken": this.refresToken , maybe it was this.refreshToken

Answer (score 0):

Do you get an error message for a cyclic dependency ? Making an HTTP request from within the HTTP interceptor might be throwing it.